# IF ELSE THEN execute SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to ask is it possible to fire a query when one of my query returns t true? Here are my sample code

```
WITH tbl AS (select x.id, x.quantity , IIF(z.Status = 'Hired', 1,0) AS Hired
FROM open_ijo x 
LEFT JOIN applicants_detail y ON y.ijoID=x.id
LEFT JOIN career_status z ON z.id=y.status
WHERE y.ijoid=x.id
AND y.status<>'8'
AND z.status<>'Open'
AND z.status <> 'withdrawn'
AND ijodateposted IS NOT NULL)

SELECT id, quantity, SUM(hired) AS hired
FROM tbl
GROUP BY id, quantity
```

The output is:

```
id  quantity  hired
61  6         1
62  1         1
63  1         0
```

What I want to achieve is, when the number of quantity is still not equal to hired it will show this query :

```
SELECT x.id, x.applicanteid, x.roleapplied, y.id AS ijoid, 
x.dateapplied, z.status, a.careerlevel, IIF(z.Status = 'Hired', 1,0) AS Hired
 FROM applicants_detail x
LEFT JOIN open_ijo y ON y.id=x.ijoid
LEFT JOIN career_status z ON z.id=x.status
LEFT JOIN roster a ON a.eid=x.applicantEID
WHERE y.id=x.ijoid and x.applicanteid IS NOT NULL
AND z.status <> 'Open'  AND
ijodateposted IS NOT NULL AND z.status <> 'Withdrawn'
AND x.status <> '8'
```

And when the number of quantity meet the number of hired, it will display a text that says nothing to display.

Comment: Dont want to run the second query, if at least one record is not matching or all the records should not be matching

Comment: Sight detour but since you say you are pretty new to sql this is well worth posting. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 Aliases should have some basis in meaning or your code becomes very difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use [IF...ELSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql)

```
IF EXISTS (QUERY1)
QUERY2
```

Comment: How am I gonna use it accordingly. I'm confused. I read the document, but not sure where to use it on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `IF .. ELSE` construct but that's possible only within a procedural code (i.e, inside a stored procedure or stored function ...) within `BEGIN .. END` block.

But if you want to access the other query value inline then you can wrap that query as subquery and then all the columns from inner/sub query can be accessed in outer query ... BUT looks like that's not what you want.

Comment: Pretty sure the statement about `IF...ELSE` requiring to be within a stored procedure or similar is false, also `BEGIN...END` is not required for one-liners.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, No, it's not. try it out

Comment: I just did with `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2` for example:
`DECLARE @i INT = 1
IF @i = 0
PRINT 'yes'
ELSE
PRINT 'no'` (just imagine line breaks in there :))

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, Yes true for SqlServer (as msdn doc says) but didn't answer keeping SqlServer in mind.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, yeah but `if..else` is always a procedural construct

Comment: I am not disputing that. I think you should just point out that this is the ANSI (I guess, is it?) way and you can take some shortcuts if you use the T-SQL-specific stuff...